# React good practice from parent state to children props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So i've been reading a lot lately on react state and props.
My app wasn't that big, but now i'm facing a problem that seems to be commun for a lot of people, and i'm trying to find the best way to implement this.

My app is simple. A SearchBar on top, that display a list of contact. My search bar is a component and is updating a react-redux store with the results of the searchBar value (calling a backend with axios). Till here everything works great.

When the results array is populate (in redux store), my container rerender the results array. Like this:

```
class Suggestions extends Component {


  render() {
    console.log('before map: ', this.props.contacts);

    const {
      contacts,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;

    const options = contacts.map((contact, index) => (
      <Contact
        key={contact.id}
        renderToaster={renderToasterFunction}
        contact={contact}
      />
    ));

    return <div>{options}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  contacts: state.contact.results,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Suggestions);
```

The problem happen in my Contact component, My list is a lirs of sometimes 10 contacts that are display on the same page. So my problem is that each Contact component need to have it's own state (to add or edit info exemple: if you need to add a new phone number).

```
//contact component
state = {
    contactState: ???
}
...
render(){
    //exemple for simplicity
    return <div>{this.state.contactState.name}</div> 
}
```

I've founded on react website that it's not a good idea to copy props from parent in state of child. And in my case i've seen it, because if i do this

```
...
state = {
    contactState: this.props.contact <--info from parent
}
```

first search is ok, but second search with an other letter, results list is not updated and i still see some results of first search.

so i've tried to change my contact component to this:

```
//contact component
state = {
    contactState: ???
}
...
render(){
    //exemple for simplicity
    return <input value={this.props.contact.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/> 
}
```

And this is working great in term of visual update, all my contact are update even if i do 3-4 searches. But my problem is that, now when i want to edit the name i need to store all my contactState somewhere before saving this and second problem, because my component display {this.props.contact.name} when i edit this, the user can't see the new value, because i can't edit props.

So is there a way to render state from props in a child everytime the parent state change. Or is there a way to 1) save the state when the user edit a contact and 2) display the new value he has written ?

What is the best way when dealing with .map() to have one state foreach children that can be re-renderer when the parent state change and rendering all children with their new state.

Thank you for your help.
Don't hesitate if you need more precisions.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your app showing the edit and add mode as well?

Comment: @jdc91 sorry, the problem is more general, see CraftMonkey answer. The objectif here is to have a an array in a parent component, to map it and to store in all children the value they received in their own state. But when i store the state and use the state to display data, the component doesn't rerender and when i use this.props.contact to display the data in my contact component it's re rendering on new search, but i can't then edit my contact information as state and this.props aren't the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand everything but if I get what you want to do:

- A simple solution could be to dispatch an action on the onChange
- The reducer which catch the action will update your redux store
- The props will change and the View too.

But that's will make you dispatch A LOT of actions...
Other option :

- Use a state in every Contact-Component which duplicates props
  `state = {...this.props.contact}`
- Modify the state on the change handler and use it as value too.
- Save and dispatch the "final name" to update redux store and call the api at the same moment to update in on your server

Let me know if that's clear enough

Comment: I think you have understood what i need, but every time i store this.props.contact in my state and do a second search the component doesn't re-render. So my request is made, my response is ok, my new array of results contain the new results from the database, but my function with contacts.map(...) is not called. if in my contact component i use this.props.contact directly to display the data of my contact, then it will re render but i can not edit my contact then.

Comment: Is suggestion rerendered with the right contacts as props ?